# Example of $\pi$-metrizable space

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

> A tychonoff space $X$ is $\pi$-metrizable if and only if it has a $\sigma$-locally finite
>   $\pi$-base.

Please help me to find some example of $\pi$-metrizable space.

Is it true that every $\pi$-metrizable space is a moscow space ?

---

For a space $X$,

A collection of nonempty open sets $\mathcal{A}$ , is called a $\pi$-base if for every nonempty
open set $O$, there exists $U \in\mathcal{A}$  such that $U\subset O$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theorem $3.4$ of Derrick Stover, [‘On $\pi$-metrizable spaces, their continuous images and products’](https://eudml.org/doc/32489), says that if $X$ is any Tikhonov space, and $D$ is the discrete space of cardinality $\pi w(X)$, then $X\times D^\omega$ is $\pi$-metrizable; that provides quite a few examples. In particular, let $\kappa$ be any infinite cardinal, let $D$ be the discrete space of cardinality $\kappa$, and let $X=D^\kappa$. Then $d(X)=\kappa$ by the [Hewitt-Marczewski-Pondiczery theorem](http://planetmath.org/hewittmarczewskipondiczerytheorem), so $\pi w(X)=\kappa$, and $X\cong X\times D^\omega$ is $\pi$-metrizable.

However, it follows from Corollary $2.12$ of A. V. Arhangel’skiǐ, [*Moscow spaces and topological groups*](http://topology.auburn.edu/tp/reprints/v25/tp25222.pdf), Top. Proc. 25 (2000), 383-416, that if $X\times D^\omega$ is Moscow, then so is $X$. Thus, $X\times D^\omega$ is a $\pi$-metrizable space that is not Moscow if $X$ is not Moscow.

Comment: First link is broken now. Perhaps you can update this with the whole citation. Regards.

Comment: @rschwieb: Thanks; fixed. EuDML apparently reorganized their links.

Comment: Heh, what a coincidence: Derrick was one of my classmates. I heard about this material as he was coming up with it, and was at his dissertation defense.

Answer (score 1):

Some other examples:

> **Example 1:** Every discrete space $X$ has a $\sigma$-locally finite $\pi$-base.
>
> **Example 2:** $\mathbb R$ with the uaual topology has a $\sigma$-locally finite $\pi$-base.